# Substitution happens here, as the completely-expanded BINDIR is not available in configure

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

Just now, I have set up Linux on cloud platform.

I'm trying to install python3.4 on CentOS 6.4.

I cannot go out this situation.

I don't understand what's the mean of message below.

How can I resolve this?

```
$yum install gcc
...
$./configure
...
...
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile.pre
config.status: creating Modules/Setup.config
config.status: creating Misc/python.pc
config.status: creating Misc/python-config.sh
config.status: creating Modules/ld_so_aix
config.status: creating pyconfig.h
config.status: pyconfig.h is unchanged
creating Modules/Setup
creating Modules/Setup.local
creating Makefile

$make
...
# Substitution happens here, as the completely-expanded BINDIR
# is not available in configure
sed -e "s,@EXENAME@,/usr/local/bin/python3.4m," < ./Misc/python-        config.in >python-config.py
# Replace makefile compat. variable references with shell script  compat. ones;  -> 
sed -e 's,\$(\([A-Za-z0-9_]*\)),\$\{\1\},g' < Misc/python-config.sh     >python-config
# On Darwin, always use the python version of the script, the shell
# version doesn't use the compiler customizations that are provided
# in python (_osx_support.py).
if test `uname -s` = Darwin; then \
            cp python-config.py python-config; \
    fi
```

---

I tried make again. 
Strange to say, the error message is gone.

Comment: Be aware that the default ``configure`` options aren't what you should be relying on. Avoiding any options will not result in a Python installation setup per best practices. Ignore the fact that it talks about Docker and read: http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/installing-custom-python-version-into.html

Answer (score -1):

first: `make`
then : `make install`
instead of : `make & make install`